# PyQt - Hide MainWindow and show QDialog without the taskbar icon disappearing

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I've been using the code from this example [PyQt: How to hide QMainWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538247/pyqt-how-to-hide-qmainwindow):

```
class Dialog_02(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Dialog_02, self).__init__(parent)
        # ensure this window gets garbage-collected when closed
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
    ...    

    def closeAndReturn(self):
        self.close()
        self.parent().show()

class Dialog_01(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    ...

    def callAnotherQMainWindow(self):
        self.hide()
        self.dialog_02 = Dialog_02(self)
        self.dialog_02.show()
```

It works, however when opening a second window, the window's task bar icon doesn't show. I've tried using QtGui.QDialog for the Dialog_02 as well but that gives me the same result.

How do I go about solving this?

Edit: I'm on Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing (because I don't know what platform you're on, and I don't use a task-bar myself, so I cant really test it), but try getting rid of the parent:

```
class Dialog_02(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, other_window):
        super(Dialog_02, self).__init__()
        # ensure this window gets garbage-collected when closed
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self._other_window = other_window
    ...    

    def closeAndReturn(self):
        self.close()
        self._other_window.show()
```

Comment: I have tried your method and it does work however, when calling the closeAndReturn function to return to the Main Window it fails giving me this error: self._other_window().show() -> TypeError: 'Window' object is not callable

Comment: Never mind. I had writted self._other_window().show() instead of self._other_window.show()