# How to temporarily hide the main window PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have removed the title of the main window.

Created a button that should **hide the window**, but **not close it**. *How can I implement a similar function for her?*

Comment: all widgets has `show and hide` [function](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#hide).

Comment: I tried to use hide(), but the window disappears from the taskbar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyQt: How to hide QMainWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538247/pyqt-how-to-hide-qmainwindow)

Comment: Can I implement this in one function, without using a second class?

Comment: you should put your code or program in question. please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it.

Comment: My code is too big. Requires more details. Imagine that it has one button and an empty function.

Comment: By any chance, do you mean minimize or hide?

Comment: @Bitchdragon 1. We didn't ask you the full code, but a "minimal reproducible example", please read that link to learn how to create such examples; please consider that creating such examples could take some time, and that's a required step in order to create good questions and improve your chances to receive good answers; 2. The fact that you're "bad at OOP" is irrelevant: python and Qt are OOP, you cannot use them without knowing its basics and usage; if you're "bad at it", do more efforts and improve those skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something to **minimize application**

like this button :

[image]

To minimize your application you should call `showMinimized();` function.

**look at this Qt Documentation link :**

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#showMinimized